# Analise de algoritmo imagem majoritária

Tags: algoritmo, complexidade-de-algoritmo

Ajuda em algoritmo

**Um vetor com n imagens A= [1...n] possui uma imagem majoritária I se mais do que a metade das imagens do vetor são iguais I. Você pode usar A[i] = A[j] para verificar se as imagens nas posições i e j são iguais .Mostre como resolver este problema em tempo O(nlogn) usando uma abordagem de divisão e conquista**

O que eu pensei:
Alguém aqui pode me ajudar montar um algoritmo para esse problema.
Um vetor com n imagens A= [1...n] possui uma imagem majoritária I se mais do que a metade das imagens do vetor são iguais I. Você pode usar A[i] = A[j] para verificar se as imagens nas posições i e j são iguais .Mostre como resolver este problema em tempo O(nlogn) usando uma abordagem de divisão e conquista

EDIT MINHA SOLUÇÃO:

Divide o vetor em duas parte n/2 --> A e A2 
encontrar n1 que é o elemento( imagem) majoritário de A
encontrar n2 que é o elemento (imagem) majoritária de A2
verificar se a contagem de n1 ou n2 é maior que o tamanho do meio mais 1 do vetor A.

```
Algoritmo:
majoritario(V[1......m])
 se (m==1) 
   retorna V[1]
meio= ceil(m/2) pegar o teto
L_elemento= majoritaio(V[1....meio]
R_elemento= majoritario(V[meio+1....m]
  se L_elemento == R_elemento : retornar L_elemento
L_soma = freq(V[1...m],L_elemento)
R_soma= freq(V[1...m], R_elemento)
  se R_soma > meio+1: retorna R_elemento
  se nao se L_soma> meio+1 retorna L_elemento
se não 
  retorna não tem elemento majoritario.
Freq(V[1...m], elemento)
    para i=1 até m 
       se V[1] == elemento
         conta = conta +1
retorna conta.
```

MINHA Ideia final foi essa passar as metades recursivamente .
O algoritmo majoritário tem duas chamadas recursivas .

```
2*T(n/2)
```

e a contagem de elementos é resolvida em um tempo O(n) no pior caso.
então temos uma recorrência

```
T(n) = 2T(n/2) +O(n) e pelo teorema mestre
T(n) = aT(n/b) +O(n^c)
c = logb na base a 
c = 1,a=2,b =2 ou seja 
O(nlogn)
```

Acho que seria isso a resolução, não tenho certeza.. 
Obrigado.

minha ideia era seguir nessa linha, porém não sei se estou correto.

Comment: já consegui resolver este problema. Irei postar a solução

Comment: Legal, @Matheus Francisco! Se importaria de postar a solução no campo resposta, logo abaixo?

Comment: eu postei a solução ali na pergunta logo abaixo..Eu acredito que seja daquele jeito .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divide o vetor em duas parte n/2 --> A e A2 
encontrar n1 que é o elemento( imagem) majoritário de A
encontrar n2 que é o elemento (imagem) majoritária de A2
verificar se a contagem de n1 ou n2 é maior que o tamanho do meio mais 1 do vetor A.

```
Algoritmo:
majoritario(V[1......m])
 se (m==1) 
   retorna V[1]
meio= ceil(m/2) pegar o teto
L_elemento= majoritaio(V[1....meio]
R_elemento= majoritario(V[meio+1....m]
  se L_elemento == R_elemento : retornar L_elemento
L_soma = freq(V[1...m],L_elemento)
R_soma= freq(V[1...m], R_elemento)
  se R_soma > meio+1: retorna R_elemento
  se nao se L_soma> meio+1 retorna L_elemento
se não 
  retorna não tem elemento majoritario.
Freq(V[1...m], elemento)
    para i=1 até m 
       se V[1] == elemento
         conta = conta +1
retorna conta.
```

MINHA Ideia final foi essa passar as metades recursivamente .
O algoritmo majoritário tem duas chamadas recursivas .

```
2*T(n/2)
```

e a contagem de elementos é resolvida em um tempo O(n) no pior caso.
então temos uma recorrência

```
T(n) = 2T(n/2) +O(n) e pelo teorema mestre
T(n) = aT(n/b) +O(n^c)
c = logb na base a 
c = 1,a=2,b =2 ou seja 
O(nlogn)
```